# How do you fix TSD02016 error in Database

Tags: datadude, vsdbcmd

I have a database I am using the Visual Studio 2010 Database Project tool vsdbcmd.exe to create a schema from.

```
vsdbcmd /a:Import /dsp:Sql /model:"Database" /cs:"Server=SqlServer; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

The tool is reporting an error:

> Error TSD02016,  Gen-259 (12,50) The column name is not valid.  No table name was specified.

How would I go about pinpointing where this error is originating?

I have found one resource on the internet ([http://social.msdn.microsoft.com....](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/beef9fbb-84ac-4586-ad7f-397c03be3ddb)) that points to a possibility of a keyword used incorrectly, but the error messages are not the same.

What is Gen-259?

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and was able to resolve it by using the import function in Visual Studio 2010. I created a new project and used `Project` -> `Import Database Objects and Settings`.  In the our case, there were stored procedures that had become orphans and referenced columns in a table that no longer existed.  We did have to correct some of the errors on the live system before we could get the project to fully import, but we were able to do that and create a .dbschema file which could be used as a reference in other VS projects.